# In Applescript, I'm trying to activate a menu item in Seamonkey

Tags: user-interface, scripting, applescript

I'm new to Applescript.  I've done some searching and reading and found something that is supposed to work for activating a menu item:

```
on do_menu(app_name, menu_name, menu_item)
    try
        -- bring the target application to the front
        tell application app_name
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process app_name
                tell menu bar 1
                    tell menu bar item menu_name
                        tell menu menu_name
                            click menu item menu_item
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        return true
    on error error_message
        return false
    end try
end do_menu

-- In my case I want to start Seamonkey and open the Composer window (and select it) so I
-- do:
do_menu("SeaMonkey", "Windows", "Composer")
```

When I run that the event log window shows:

```
tell application "SeaMonkey"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    click menu item "Composer" of menu "Windows" of menu bar item "Windows" of menu bar 1 of process "SeaMonkey"
        --> error number -1728 from «class mbri» "Windows" of «class mbar» 1 of «class prcs» "SeaMonkey"
end tell
```

Result:
false

I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Error number -1728 seems to be a generic "not found" error in AppleScript. I don't see a *Windows* menu in SeaMonkey, but I do see a *Window* menu. Try dropping the "s" from *Windows*.

Also, I think you might need to enable "access for assistive devices" for the "click" to work, you'll get an error message to that effect if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

@mu is too short has it correct.  Remove the 's' from 'Windows' and it will work.  Here's the condensed version though if you don't want to deal with using handlers.

```
activate application "SeaMonkey"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SeaMonkey"
        click menu item "Composer" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```